# How do I dynamically create a list of lists?

Tags: list, tcl

I understand that I can create a "list of lists" as shown below, but I would like to create "d" as a part of a procedure (append $x (x=a,b,c) dynamically).
Can someone help me understand this? I do not believe lappend works with this as it only adds the list elements to the existing list. So this is a 2 dimensional list. I am clear on how to access the nested lists once the 2 dimensional list is created. Any thoughts ?

```
set a [list x y z]
set b [list u v w]
set c [list i j k]
set d [list $a $b $c] #I want to create this as a part of a procedure

foreach m $d {
    puts "++++++++++++"
    foreach n $m {
    puts $n
    }
}

sleepy> ./listOflist.tcl
+++++++
x
y
z
+++++++
u
v
w
+++++++
i
j
k
sleepy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest case, you just do:

```
proc 2D {m n} {
    set result {}
    set letter 96
    for {set i 0} {$i < $m} {incr i} {
        set row {}
        for {set j 0} {$j < $n} {incr j} {
            lappend row [format "%c" [incr letter]]
        }
        lappend result $row
    }
    return $result
}
```

That's fine, but if you want to extend one of those inner rows? `lset`! It lets you put an element after the end of any list at any depth.

```
% set basic2Darray [2D 3 3]
{a b c} {d e f} {g h i}
% lset basic2Darray 0 end+1 x;     # <<< see the end+1?
{a b c x} {d e f} {g h i}
```